# Security Error on WordPress site using WooCommerce, cleaner theme and PayPal

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, security-warning

I am using a combination of things and not sure where the error is coming from:  I have a WordPress site with and installed SSL cert. https:www.joesmetrobox.com.  I have the Cleanr theme installed and I am using WooCommerce and the Paypal Advanced plug in to use Paypal as the way I process payments.

Everything is fine until I try to submit the credit card information here: on this page: checkout/pay/?key=order_51882ad846e67&order=360 (this would be unique for transaction).  Then depending on the browser I get an error:

Firefox: Security Warning: Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by others. Are you sure you want to continue sending this information?
Firebug gives me this

> error: 404 error for this
>   wp-content/themes/cleanr/js/scripts.js?ver=1.0  and file which does
>   not seem to exist.

Explorer 8: Security Warning: Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securely? This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire webpage.

Chrome: Secure Token Expired
and if I use their developer tools I also get this extra clue: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL https://joesmetrobox.com/checkout/pay/?key=order_5188245e1ae70&order=361 from frame with URL https://payflowlink.paypal.com/?mode=LIVE&SECURETOKEN=LvNtL1gubfE6Z5lwc2gMiQgJ0&SECURETOKENID=joesmetro51882d664015d4.15989435. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

So I am pretty stumped at this point where to even focus my attention.  I am not a programmer and know just enough to be dangerous.

I am wondering if it is some kind of token setting in Paypal that I accidentally clicked and don't need?  or maybe WooCommerce isn't playing nice with Paypal, Cleanr theme or maybe both.

I just want to be able to process payments without an error popping up...does anyone have ideas?

Comment: oops one other thing...it's when this payment option is used: Credit Card or PayPal Payment (not PayPal Regular)

Answer (score 0):

a plugin like this may help you implement HTTPS to your site.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/

WooCommerce Reference: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/ssl-and-https/

> Insecure content warnings
>
> If you have insecure content warnings when viewing a secure page it
>   means you will be linking directly to scripts, images, or stylesheets
>   over http instead of https. Most of the time this is simply fixed by
>   changing said links to https or by using relative URL’s (e.g.
>   /wp-content/file instead of http yoursitename/wp-content/file).
>
> You can also use a plugin like WordPress HTTPS to force the URLS to be
>   secure. WooCommerce does secure scripts which are enqueued correctly.
>
> To identify the insecure links you can use a tool such as Firebug for
>   firefox, or Chromes built in developer tools, and look at the error
>   console – insecure resources will be listed.

Comment: Thank you Robert for the suggestion.  I did try that particular plug in which is how I found firebug and Chrome developer tools and did give me some leads but the plug in itself didn't resolve the problem.  I think because it has something to do with something that is not under my control... the link to payflow.

Comment: It seems that all your links are not setup under https so you would need to fix your function.php file on your theme and plugins to reflect https + your site does not directly go to a https site instead it seems to be going to http joesmetrobox.com which you should fix as well.

Comment: you could also use something like w3 total cache to compress all your files and have it link as a https maybe.  something to consider as well. :)

Comment: Hi Robert!  So I exceptionally proud of myself :)  I finally tracked down the problem.  When I got my SSL cert and installed it I forgot to change some critical files in Paypal from http to https.  I did it and that fixed it!  Thanks for your ideas, I appreciate the added brain power.